# Increment Oracle time in varchar field by a certain amount?

Tags: sql, oracle, time, plsql

We have times stored in an Oracle varchar(5) field.

Times stored using HH24:MI (ie: 22:30, 10:15).

How can we run a query that will increase or decrease these times by a certain amount?  Ie: increase by one hour or decrease by 45 minutes.

Comment: What's `23:45 + 45` supposed to be? `24:30` or `00:30`?

Comment: I'd assume that situation won't exist.  But if it did - 00:30

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use the built-in date (and [interval](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598) -- thanks [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole) for the link) calculation:

```
to_char(to_date(:x, 'hh24:mi') + INTERVAL :y MINUTE,'hh24:mi')
```

for instance:

```
SQL> WITH my_data AS (
  2     SELECT '12:15' t FROM dual
  3     UNION ALL SELECT '10:30' FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT t, 
  6         to_char(to_date(t, 'hh24:mi') + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE,'hh24:mi')"t+15"
  7    FROM my_data;

T     t+15
----- -----
12:15 12:30
10:30 10:45
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Looks like the keyword `HOUR` works in addition to `MINUTE`

Comment: @Marcus there's more on intervals [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598).

Answer (score 1):

The functions to convert from/to date and char are `TO_DATE()` and `TO_CHAR()`:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE('31/12/2001 23:55:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "DATE",
    TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "CHAR"
FROM DUAL
```

So you can do:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE('23:45', 'HH24:MI'),
    TO_DATE('23:45', 'HH24:MI') + INTERVAL '45' MINUTE,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('23:45', 'HH24:MI') + interval '45' MINUTE, 'HH24:MI')
FROM DUAL
```

There're possibly other better ways to do it (I'm not sure this will work as expected if ran when DST is about to start) but I'm still learning :)